# The value of the pointer pointed to by the double pointer is lost (c code)

Tags: c, pointers, sip, sdp, double-pointer

I am working on  a c code that does some manipulation on SIP messages to be more specific it extracts values from the SDP body of the message. I am not a professional in c, but using the knowledge I gained from a course in my university I wrote my code.

The problem is that a double pointer is created inside the function get_m_line_f(str body) and returned from it. This double pointer points to two pointers of the type str*. each one of them has a char pointer which is pointing to the start of the chunk that I want from my sting (the chunk happens to be m=......\r\n) and the length of that chunk.

when I check the values pointed at by the pointers from whith in the function they are correct, but when I check the values from the returned double pointer they are wrong, eventhough as you can see the addresses pointed from inside the double pointer did not change. please check the code and the output below and you will understand the problem better. thanks in advance

This is part of my main funtion:

```
    int main(void) {

str body;
str ip;
str ports;
str m_line;

str *m_line_ptr_one;
str *m_line_ptr_two;

str *port_ptr_one;
str *port_ptr_two;

str **m_lines;
str **double_ptr_two;

char msg[] = "INVITE sip:13@10.10.1.13 SIP/2.0 \r\n"
        "Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.10.1.99:5060;branch=z9hG4bK343bf628;rport\r\n"
        "From: \"Test 15\" <sip:15@10.10.1.99>;tag=as58f4201b\r\n"
        "To: <sip:13@10.10.1.13>\r\n"
        "Contact: <sip:15@10.10.1.99>\r\n"
        "Call-ID: 326371826c80e17e6cf6c29861eb2933@10.10.1.99\r\n"
        "CSeq: 102 INVITE\r\n"
        "User-Agent: Asterisk PBX\r\n"
        "Max-Forwards: 70\r\n"
        "Date: Wed, 06 Dec 2009 14:12:45 GMT\r\n"
        "Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER,SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY\r\n"
        "Supported: replaces\r\n"
        "Content-Type: application/sdp\r\n"
        "Content-Length: 258\r\n"
        "\r\n"
        "v=0\r\n"
        "o=root 1821 1821 IN IP4 10.10.1.99\r\n"
        "s=session\r\n"
        "c=IN IP4 10.10.1.99\r\n"
        "t=0 0\r\n"
        "m=audio 11424 RTP/AVP 0 8 101\r\n"
        "m=video 12324 RTP/AVP 0 8 101\r\n"
        "c=IN IP4 10.10.1.99\r\n"
        "a=sendrcv\r\n";


body.s = msg;
body.len = strlen(msg);

m_lines = get_m_line_f(body);

printf("the addresses after they are returned\naudio: %p\nvideo: %p\n",*m_lines,*(m_lines + sizeof(struct str*)));

printf("Output from the pointer after it is returned\n %.*s\n", (*m_lines)->len,(*m_lines)->s);
printf("Output from the pointer after it is returned\n %.*s\n", (*(m_lines + sizeof(struct str*)))->len, (*(m_lines + sizeof(struct str*)))->s);


double_ptr_two = get_m_port(m_lines);
```

The get_m_line_f(str body) function is

```
struct str **get_m_line_f(str body){


str m_audio;
str *m_audio_ptr;
m_audio_ptr = &m_audio;

str m_video;
str *m_video_ptr;
m_video_ptr = &m_video;

str **m_lines;
m_lines = (str**)malloc(2*sizeof(str*));


if(m_lines == NULL){
    printf("cannot allocate PKG memory\n");
    return NULL;
}


int len;

if (body.s == 0){
    printf("Failed to get message body\n");
    return NULL;
}


if (body.len == 0){
    printf("message body has zero length\n");
    return NULL;
}


for (int i=0;i<=body.len;++i){
    if(*(body.s+i) == 'm' && *(body.s+i+1) == '='){
        if(strncmp(body.s+i+2,"audio",strlen("audio")) == 0){
                m_audio.s = body.s+i;
        } else if(strncmp(body.s+i+2,"video",strlen("video")) == 0){
            m_video.s = body.s+i;
        }
    }
}


if(m_audio.s != NULL){
    for(len=0;*(m_audio.s+len) != '\n';++len);
    m_audio.len = len;
    *(m_lines) = m_audio_ptr;
} else{
    printf("No \"m=audio\" line is found\n");
    return NULL;
}

if(m_video.s != NULL){
        for(len=0;*(m_video.s+len) != '\n';++len);
        m_video.len = len;
        *(m_lines + sizeof(struct str*)) = m_video_ptr;
    } else{
        printf("No \"m=video\"  line is found\n");
        return NULL;
    }

printf("output from the double pointer in the function where its created\n %.*s\n", (*m_lines)->len,(*m_lines)->s);
printf("output from the double pointer in the function where its created\n %.*s\n", (*(m_lines + sizeof(struct str*)))->len, (*(m_lines + sizeof(struct str*)))->s);


printf("Checking the addresses to be returned\naudio: %p\nvideo: %p\n",*m_lines,*(m_lines + sizeof(struct str*)));

return m_lines;
}
```

the str struct is very simple:

```
typedef struct str{
    char* s;
    int len;
} str;
```

The output of my code is as follows:

```
output from the double pointer in the function where its created
m=audio 11424 RTP/AVP 0 8 101

output from the double pointer in the function where its created
m=video 12324 RTP/AVP 0 8 101

Checking the addresses to be returned
audio: 0x7fff52db0848
video: 0x7fff52db0830
the addresses after they are returned
audio: 0x7fff52db0848
video: 0x7fff52db0830
Output from the pointer after it is returned
m=audio 11424 RTP/AVP 0 8 101

m=video 12324 RTP/AVP 0 8 101

c=IN IP4 10.10.1.99

a=sendrcv
```

Comment: Undefined behavior for accessing an object with automatic storage duration after its lifetime has ended.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your program, below.  There are two errors.

- One error is in how you address `m_lines`, but I think your confusion arose from thinking about "double pointers", when what you really have -- in effect -- is a pointer to an array.
- The *effective* "pointer to an array" is `m_lines`.  Its elements are pointers.  Unfortunately, they are pointers that point to the local variables `m_audio` and `m_video`.  That storage is not available to the calling function.  When `get_m_line_f` returns, the memory pointed to by the `m_lines` elements is no longer defined.

I made the problem more obvious by neatening style a bit, and by using array notation.  My changes are indicated with `//`-style comments.

The worst problem is this line:

```
*(m_lines + sizeof(struct str*)) = m_video_ptr;
```

`m_lines` is defined as `str**`, a pointer to 2 pointers.  To illustrate how array notation clarifies the issue, the above is equivalent to

```
m_lines[sizeof(struct str*)] = m_video_ptr;
```

which means you're assigning to `m_lines[12]` or so, probably not what you meant, and definitely not what you allocated!

In attempting to debug that, you print out the values.  Of course, you dereference `m_lines` in exactly the way you assigned to it, and for that brief, shining moment the memory you stomped on still has what you put there.  I changed the assignment and left your print logic alone; it will now show the strangeness you expected.

You would benefit from changing the function to return an array of `str` instead.  Then you could use that array in place, eliminating the local variables.  IOW, instead of

```
  str **m_lines = malloc(2 * sizeof(str*)); // do not cast malloc
```

define `m_lines` as

```
  str *m_lines = calloc(2, sizeof(str));
```

That way,

- you can reference `m_lines[0]` and `m_lines[1]`
- you've allocated *all* the storage pointed to by the variable you're returning.

As a rule, *any* assignment of the address of a local variable is a sign of trouble.  Sometimes we pass an address into a function.  Returning one, no matter how indirectly, is almost always an error.

Here's your program somewhat patched up, but not correct.  You'll have to decide whether to change the function definition, or to allocate `m_audio` and `m_video` on the heap.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct str {
  char *s; // put the * by the variable. 
  int len;
} str;

struct str **
get_m_line_f(str body)
{
  // initialize when defining
  str m_audio, *m_audio_ptr = &m_audio;
  str m_video, *m_video_ptr = &m_video;

  str **m_lines = malloc(2 * sizeof(str*)); // do not cast malloc

  if(m_lines == NULL){
    printf("cannot allocate PKG memory\n");
    return NULL;
  }

  if (body.s == NULL) { // s is a pointer
    printf("Failed to get message body\n");
    return NULL;
  }


  if (body.len == 0){
    printf("message body has zero length\n");
    return NULL;
  }

  int len;

  for (int i=0; i <= body.len; ++i) {
    // could use 0 == memcmp(body.s+i, "m=", 2)
    if (body.s[i] == 'm' && body.s[i+1] == '=') {
      // use compile-time constants
      static const char audio[] = "audio", video[] = "video";
      if (strncmp(body.s+i+2, audio, sizeof(audio) - 1) == 0) {
        m_audio.s = body.s+i;
      } else if(strncmp(body.s+i+2, video, sizeof(video) - 1) == 0) {
        m_video.s = body.s+i;
      }
    }
  }

  if (m_audio.s != NULL) {
    for (len=0; m_audio.s[len] != '\n'; ++len);
    m_audio.len = len;
    m_lines[0] = m_audio_ptr;
  } else{
    printf("No \"m=audio\" line is found\n");
    return NULL;
  }

  if(m_video.s != NULL) {
    for(len=0;*(m_video.s+len) != '\n';++len);
    m_video.len = len;
    if (false ) { // vvv addressing error here vvv
      *(m_lines + sizeof(struct str*)) = m_video_ptr;
    } else {
      m_lines[1] = m_video_ptr;
    }
  } else {
    printf("No \"m=video\"  line is found\n");
    return NULL;
  }

  printf("output from the double pointer in the function where its created\n %.*s\n", (*m_lines)->len,(*m_lines)->s);
  printf("output from the double pointer in the function where its created\n %.*s\n", (*(m_lines + sizeof(struct str*)))->len, (*(m_lines + sizeof(struct str*)))->s);


  printf("Checking the addresses to be returned\naudio: %p\nvideo: %p\n", (void*)*m_lines, (void*)*(m_lines + sizeof(struct str*)));

  return m_lines;
}
```

Comment: Your changes are giving the same output of my code which means they did not solve the problem. Howerver your commints are really valuable and I benefited from them. Thanks a lot